# Python IF multiple "and" "or" in one statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, if-statement

I am just wondering if this following if statement works:

```
    value=[1,2,3,4,5,f]
    target = [1,2,3,4,5,6,f]
    if value[0] in target OR value[1] in target AND value[6] in target:
       print ("good")
```

My goal is to make sure the following 2 requirements are all met at the same time:
1. value[6] must be in target
2. either value[0] or value[1] in target
Apologize if I made a bad example but my question is that if I could make three AND & OR in one statement?  Many thanks!

Comment: You will index error when you will try to access value[6] and apart of that, what is f in value list, is that some variable or element of list, if this is the element of list, then you should enclose it under single or double quote.

Comment: What course materials are you using that instruct you to use `AND` and `OR` in uppercase?

Comment: @Pramod got it! thx!

Comment: @TigerhawkT3   actually i put them in uppercase cuz it helps ppl quickly understand what my question is. nothing to do with ANY course materials

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use *parenthesis* to group the conditions:

```
if value[6] in target and (value[0] in target or value[1] in target):
```

Note that you can make the `in` lookups in constant time if you would define the `target` as a set:

```
target = {1,2,3,4,5,6,f}
```

---

And, as mentioned by @Pramod in comments, in this case `value[6]` would result in an `IndexError` since there are only 6 elements defined in `value` and indexing is 0-based.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong ***and*** has priority, so doing:

```
if x==True or y==True and z==True:
    do smth
```

would be like doing:

```
if x==True or (y==True and z==True):
```

not like doing:

```
(if x==True or y==True) and z==True:
```

But as @alecxe commented, it is always safer to use *()* when more than 2 logic arguments are used.