# how can i make an if command need multiple things in order to perform a command

Tags: python

I have this code with handling a draw in tic-tac-toe

```py
def end_of_game():
  if grid[0][0] and grid[1][0] and grid[2][0] and grid[0][1] and grid[0][2] and grid[1][1] and grid[1][2] and grid[2][1] and grid[2][2] == 1 or 2:
    print("game is a draw")
    exit()

# 1 = x
# 2 = O
```

after every placement it outputs "game is a draw" how do I make it so all of them have to = 1 or 2 in order to print "game is a draw"

Comment: Your `if` statement will always evaluate true because `2` counts as `true`.  This post may be helpful in learning how `and` and `or` work with each other https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36298231/python-if-multiple-and-or-in-one-statement

Comment: `==` has higher precedence over `and`, so your code will be executed like this: `if (grid[0][0] and grid[1][0] and grid[2][0] and grid[0][1] and grid[0][2] and grid[1][1] and grid[1][2] and grid[2][1] and (grid[2][2] == 1)) or (2):` which is always true, so you should use `==` with every condition.

Comment: Everyone has explained the issues fairly well. i'll try to just help you solve the problem without going into a ton of detail. sorry. `if all(map(lambda x:x in ["1", "2"], [x for x in grid for x in x])): print("Game is a draw")`.

Comment: `all()` checks that all values are true. `map()` applies a function to every item in an iterable. `lambda` is an unbound inline function. and I flatten the list of lists with a `generator`. sorry again that I won't provide much detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`and` is a logical operator that takes two boolean operands. For example, `True and False` evaluates to `False`. When you write `grid[2][1] and grid[2][2] == 1`, `grid[2][1]` is implicitly converted to a boolean, `grid[2][2] == 1` is evaluated on its own, after which the `and` operation is performed between the two. What you really want is `grid[2][1] == 1 and grid[2][2] == 1`

Comment: how would I test for 2 aswell (also thanks for the help)

Comment: Method 1: `a == 1 or a ==2`. Method 2: `a in [1,2]`.

Comment: ah thanks jafar i get what to do now